# Dynamic Facets in Elastic Search using Nest Client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need a way to control building a facet without only using the nest fluent api. The main need is that I may need to include or exclude allterms or facetfilters.

The code below works but to change the facet, I would need to recompile. I see that it takes a Func but I have been unable to return the correct type to get this working.

```
        sd.FacetTerm("Name", t => t 
            .OnField("Field")
            .Size(facet.Size)
            .AllTerms()
        );
```

The code below doesn't work and I'm sure why. When debugging, I see that it creates the facet term but without any of the data that "FacetBuilder" provided.

```
    sd.FacetTerm(facet.Name, t => FacetBuilder(options));


    public TermFacetDescriptor<CatalogMapping> FacetBuilder(FacetOptions options)
    {
        var facet = new TermFacetDescriptor<CatalogMapping>();
        facet.OnField(options.Field);

        facet.Size(options.Size);
        if (options.IncludeAllTerms)
            facet.AllTerms();

        return facet;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to pass an object reference and modify that instance.

```
public TermFacetDescriptor<CatalogMapping> FacetBuilder(TermFacetDescriptor<CatalogMapping> termFacet, FacetOptions options)
    {
        termFacet.OnField(options.Field);
        termFacet.Size(options.Size);

        if (options.IncludeAllTerms)
            termFacet.AllTerms();

        return termFacet;
    }
```

Comment: My eternal struggle to `Func<T, T>` or to `Action<T>` :)